# Prometheus aggregate data to larger time range

Tags: prometheus, grafana, victoriametrics

I have some counter in Prometheus (Victoria metrics).

In Grafana I'm displaying it like this:

```
sum by (model_id) (increase(requests[$__interval]))
```

I would like to add variable in grafana, called downsample. Where I could pick `1h`, or `6h` or something. I want to see my data aggregated based on this time. Like if I say `1h`, I would like my graph to have 1 point per hour with total number of requests per model during this hour.

The `$__interval` seems to change by grafana based on my time window. But If I try to put my `1h` I get something completely untrue.

Answer (score 5):

> But If I try to put my `1h` I get something completely untrue.

You are getting correct data, it's just your interpretation is a bit wrong.

When you query `sum by (model_id) (increase(requests[1h]))` you got as a result total increase over last hour (from point on graph) for ever `model_id`. But it doesn't change steps of graph.

If you want to have a possibility for user to easily enforce bigger steps on graph, you can create Interval dashboard variable, ans use it (in form `$myvariable` in *Min step* option of Panel data (Query options above the query editor). And keep your query as is.

This will allow to set minimal step of graph. But be advised that you are not forcing Grafana to use it: Grafana can use even bigger value if needed. For example it prevents users from passing `1s` as an interval, while having dashboard over last year, sending Grafana, Prometheus and network into a bit of troubles.

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: `sum(increase(istio_requests_total{request_host="host", cluster="5pjc2gr2xcpwzewbpax6p6", url_path="/"}[60s]))` at the end this query works for me, but can you please explain why if I hit multiple time execute this query can return sometimes different values?

Comment: @Anatoly, [grafana advises](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/prometheus/template-variables/#use-__rate_interval) to use `[$__rate_interval]` instead of `[60s]`. (But this is not related to issue you encountered)

Comment: @Anatoly, the issue you have is that depending on time you push your button you have different results for increase. Probably scrape interval in data source config is not the same as real scrape interval of your Prometheus jobs. Also, if you'll set minstep option of query to recommended in answer variable with sufficiently big value (and use `[$__rate_interval]`) this should not happen.