# Prometheus metrics to measure number of requests to the endpoint

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am working with a Prometheus query where I aim to create a chart that shows data points for the last 24 hours (it will vary, 1h, 1d, 1w, 1y) where each point represents the number of requests received in the preceding minute. Here is the initial query I was working with:

```
istio_requests_total{request_host="REDACTED_HOSTNAME", cluster="REDACTED_CLUSTER_ID", url_path="/"}
```

This gives me the following response:

| response | value |
| --- | --- |
| istio_requests_total{cluster="cluster_id", connection_security_policy="unknown", container="container_name", destination_app="unknown", destination_canonical_revision="latest", destination_canonical_service="service_name", destination_cluster="Kubernetes", destination_principal="unknown", destination_service="service_name.service_namespace.svc.cluster.local", destination_service_name="service_name", destination_service_namespace="service_namespace", destination_version="unknown", destination_workload="workload_name", destination_workload_namespace="workload_namespace", endpoint="endpoint_name", instance="instance_ip:port", job="job_name", namespace="namespace_name", pod="pod_name", receive="true", reporter="source", request_host="redacted_url", request_protocol="protocol_name", response_code="response_code", response_flags="-", service="service_name", source_app="source_app_name", source_canonical_revision="latest", source_canonical_service="service_name", source_cluster="Kubernetes", source_principal="unknown", source_workload="workload_name", source_workload_namespace="namespace_name", tenant_id="tenant_id", url_path="/path"} | 13 |

And few other objects than distinguished one from another by response_code, 200 vs 401 vs 403.

When I issue the following query:

```
sum(istio_requests_total{request_host="REDACTED_HOSTNAME", cluster="REDACTED_CLUSTER_ID", url_path="/"})
```

I get this result:

| response | value |
| --- | --- |
| {} | 14 |

When I try to show this on graph I get something like this:

[image]

What I want to create is a spike chart, where each spike displays the number of requests from the previous minute or day (this time frame should be configurable). How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify, by spike chart, do you mean bar chart, or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prometheus aggregate data to larger time range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77012421/prometheus-aggregate-data-to-larger-time-range)

Comment: @markalex, yes, bar chart will solve my issue. I still didn't get it, trying now to understand this answer.

Comment: You'll need to use query `sum(increase(istio_requests_total{request_host="REDACTED_HOSTNAME", cluster="REDACTED_CLUSTER_ID", url_path="/"}[$__interval]))`.

Comment: @markalex, it's exactly what I use in my application based on client_golang, it's based on your answer that you mentioned: `sum(increase(istio_requests_total{request_host="%request_host", cluster="%cluster", url_path="%url_path"}[%durations]))` it's a template and %duration depends on time range, for example if `timerange` is day, `%duration` is minute,  week = hour, etc...  In general it work, except that sometimes when range last hour values may differer from hit to hit, and I don't get the whole value, for example I get 3.007874...., etc...

Comment: To quote official documentation: "The increase is extrapolated to cover the full time range as specified in the range vector selector, so that it is possible to get a non-integer result even if a counter increases only by integer increments." It is well known behavior of `increase`, and there plenty of questions about that on SO. But there is no good 100% workaround for this.